# Symmetry of one-sided partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, reference-request, partial-derivative

Consider some $f: [0,1)\times [0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$.  I'm interested in conditions that guarantee that the following one-sided second partial derivatives at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ are symmetric:
$$
\partial_x^+ \partial_y^+ f(x,y)= \partial_y^+ \partial_x^+ f(x,y).
$$
(where as usual $\partial_x^+$  and $\partial_y^+$ indicate partial derivatives defined via one-sided limits).

Everything on the topic that I've found (such as Rudin Theorem 9.41, etc.) considers $f$ defined on an open set, where regular (not one-sided) derivatives can be defined.

Is there a set of simple condition for the above equality to hold? Is there a reference for this?

(My thought right now is to "extend" $f$ to an open set $E \supset [0,1]\times[0,1]$ in a way that preserves the derivatives.)